How to set flag_keep_screen_on from javascript
I'd like to enable or disable the screen_on feature from JAvascript inside the webview.
This is how I tried to do it
@JavascriptInterface
fun setScreenOn(screenOn: Boolean) {
    val window = m_Activity.window
    if (screenOn) {
        Log.d("screen", "addFlag")
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    } else {
        Log.d("screen", "clearFlag")
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}

Unfortunately this gives me a Java exception.
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Expected: main Calling: JavaBridge
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:11023)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2473)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:28020)
at android.view.View.setLayoutParams(View.java:20530)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:464)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:165)
at android.app.Activity.onWindowAttributesChanged(Activity.java:4364)
at android.view.Window.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(Window.java:1323)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(PhoneWindow.java:3193)
at android.view.Window.setFlags(Window.java:1309)
at android.view.Window.clearFlags(Window.java:1283)

Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Does this mean that it is not possible to change FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON from Javascript? Or is there a way to work around this?
